# How to download word,excel,power point file using php (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I trying to implement application to download word,excel,power point file which are stored in my server.My source code work fine for pdf.This is my pdf file download source code.What are the changes need to done for those three types.

```
$fullPath= 'http://192.168.12.12/test/public/video/08/01/0107_9762.pdf';
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=0108_9762.pdf");
$pdfiledata = file_get_contents($fullPath);
echo $pdfiledata;
exit;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get any errors or haven't you tried yet? Please show us what you have done so far (regarding the other filetypes). If you get stuck at that point, come back and describe the problem you found.

Comment: @tibias I tried changing the header("Content-type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");  for .docx files. file download with corrupted.Its has file size same as server file size.MS word says cant open because its corrupted.Am i missing any header.Try different codes which in the web.but its not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my problem.By anyalysing the bytes it start with space need to clear that space.This is the work code for anyone.**

```
                $fullPath = $fullPath= 'http://192.168.12.12/test/public/doc/08/01/0107_9762.docx';
                $fileName = "mydoc.docx";
                $headers = get_headers($fullPath, 1);
                $contentType = $headers['Content-Type'];
                ob_start("");
                header("Content-type:".$contentType);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName); 
                ob_end_clean();
                $pdfiledata = file_get_contents($fullPath);
                ob_clean();   // discard any data in the output buffer (if possible)
                flush();      // flush headers (if possible)
                echo $pdfiledata;
                exit;
```